# How can I make an IntStream from a byte array?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I already know there are only `IntStream` and `LongStream`. How can I make an `IntStream` from a byte array?

Currently I'm planning to do like this.

```
static int[] bytesToInts(final byte[] bytes) {
    final int[] ints = new int[bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
    }
    return ints;
}

static IntStream bytesToIntStream(final byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.of(bytesToInt(bytes));
}
```

Is there any easier or faster way to do this?

Comment: A follow-up question about converting bytes array into a hex string. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27181383/330457

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variant of Radiodef's answer:

```
static IntStream bytesToIntStream(byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
        .map(i -> bytes[i] & 0xFF)
    ;
}
```

Easier to guarantee parallelization, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
static IntStream bytesToIntStream(byte[] bytes) {
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
    return IntStream
        .generate(() -> bytes[i.getAndIncrement()] & 0xFF)
        .limit(bytes.length);
}
```

but it's not very pretty. (It's not so bad though: usage of `AtomicInteger` allows the stream to be run in parallel.)

Comment: Actually, using an `AtomicInteger` here does not create any benefit regarding parallel processing as the `Stream` doesn’t know that you are using it. It will therefore assume no parallel capabilities. Not that it matters for a `Supplier` where each item creation depends on the result state of the previous…

Comment: @Holger Can you not call `parallel()` on the stream? Or is it only a hint?

Comment: You can call `parallel` on the stream and it will do it’s best to perform operations in parallel but the `Supplier` will not be queried concurrently and hence become a bottleneck. But even if it was called concurrently, the `AtomicInteger` is likely to become a bottleneck as it serializes all updates. That’s a big difference to the accepted answer which does not need concurrent updates at all.

Answer (score 2):

One line code:

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
IntStream in = Bytes.asList(bytes).stream().mapToInt(i-> i & 0xFF);
```