# Effective way to get hex string from a byte array using lambdas and streams

Tags: lambda, hex, java-8, java-stream

This is a follow-up question of [How can I make an IntStream from a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27181026/330457)

I created a method converting given byte array to a joined hex string.

```java
static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes) {

    return IntStream.rang(0, bytes.length * 2)
        .map(i -> (bytes[i / 2] >> ((i & 0x01) == 0 ? 4 : 0)) & 0x0F)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toHexString)
        .collect(joining());
}
```

My question is that, not using any 3rd party libraries, is above code effective enough? Did I do anything wrong or unnecessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
        .mapToObj(i->String.format("%02x", bytes[i]&0xff))
        .collect(joining());
}
```

though the following might be more efficient:

```
static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                 (sb,i)->new Formatter(sb).format("%02x", bytes[i]&0xff),
                 StringBuilder::append).toString();
}
```

Both support parallel processing.

Comment: As a side note, there is a simple, stream-free solution: `new BigInteger(bytes).toString(16)`…

Comment: I see `-75e0` from `BigInteger#toString(16)`.

Comment: Oh. I found an another constructor with `signum`.